# A kind word and forgiveness II

Tags: grammaticality, singular-vs-plural

Posting a new question to make things clear, to avoid confusion.

Which one is grammatical?

```
A kind word and forgiveness is good. 

A kind word and forgiveness are good.
```

Comment: Someone referred you to [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/61669/v-ing-and-v-ing-is-vs-v-ing-and-v-ing-are). It depends whether you think of the two things as separate, or as parts of the same behaviour (the kind word expresses forgiveness).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [V-ing and V-ing is vs. V-ing and V-ing are](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/61669/v-ing-and-v-ing-is-vs-v-ing-and-v-ing-are)

Comment: @KateBunting: Is there a reason you posted the link but didn't vtc?

Comment: @FumbleFingers - No particular reason.